# Canvas performance - better to draw to an offscreen canvas first?

Tags: html, canvas

As the question states - will canvas performance be faster if we do all our drawing in an off-screen buffer, then draw that buffer to the on-screen canvas, or does it not matter?

I'm drawing a lot of rectangles + small images on each draw loop. It works extremely well on ios, but on android phones it's pretty horrible. But maybe the browser implementation is doing this for us under the covers already.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will help if you do this in order to cache part of the image. If you just draw everything to it and then copy to on-screen canvas, then it's not worth the effort.

- use multiple canvases one over another to draw parts of the image separately (use one for rarely updated drawing, and another only for parts which change often)
- use off-screen canvas for shapes which don't change, but move around in main canvas.

Comment: What if you have several large canvases that are updated at 60fps, but only need small lower-fps previews for most of them ([example](http://meemoo.org/iframework/#gist/3124854))?

Comment: "use off-screen canvas for shapes which don't change" - slightly related to this - how many would it take for performance to be hindered and not helped? eg Would three be OK?